# Haskell -- Instance constraints bindings

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell programming language to understand functional programming paradigm.

I was trying to write following code

```
class Area shape where
area :: (Num n) => shape n -> n

data Quadrilateral t = Rectangle {length::t, width::t} | Square {side::t} deriving(Show)

data CircularShape t = Circle {radius::t} deriving(Show)

instance Area Quadrilateral where
    area (Rectangle l w) =  l * w
    area (Square s ) = s * s

instance Area CircularShape where
    area (Circle r) = pi * r * r

main = do
        putStrLn . show . area $ Rectangle 10.0 20.0
        putStrLn . show . area $ Square 10
        putStrLn . show . area $ Circle 10.0
```

Here is the link for [code](http://codepad.org/y9O8aK5W)

I am getting error below,

```
Error occurred
ERROR line 13 - Cannot justify constraints in instance member binding
*** Expression    : area
*** Type          : (Area CircularShape, Num a) => CircularShape a -> a
*** Given context : (Area CircularShape, Num a)
*** Constraints   : Floating a
```

I am not able to understand the exact cause of this error. This code was working fine before adding the CircularShape data and it's corresponding instance of Area typeclass.

How I can solve this if I want to use both Quadrilateral and CircularShape ?

Comment: Just a comment, don't use `typeclasses` to do subtyping. That's a known antipattern: http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Comment: It's cleaner in this case to do `data Shape a = Circle a | Square a | Rectangle a a` then you don't need typeclasses and can define `area :: (Floating a) => Shape a -> a` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we are using different compiler, I show you the output of my error window.

```
box.hs|14 col 23 error| Could not deduce (Floating n) arising from a use of ‘pi’
|| from the context (Num n)
||   bound by the type signature for
||              area :: Num n => CircularShape n -> n
||   at /Users/evan/box.hs:14:5-8
|| Possible fix:
||   add (Floating n) to the context of
||     the type signature for area :: Num n => CircularShape n -> n
|| In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘pi’
|| In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘pi * r’
|| In the expression: pi * r * r
```

Basically, in your typeclass declaration, n is bound into Num which is too generic if you want to multiply it with pi, which is a floating point type.

Try changing `Num` into `Floating`

```
class Area shape where
    area :: (Floating n) => shape n -> n
```

You might get a warning of something like "Defaulting to Double" which is because there are two floating types in haskell, (i.e Float and Double)

Answer (score 1):

Change the type signature of area to

```
area:: (Floating n) => shape n -> n
```

Your code didn't work because multiplication with `pi` requires the type constraint `Floating a`

Also use `print` instead of `putStrLn . show`